# bash script+jq: contains(), should match an exact string

Tags: bash, shell, jq

```
jq --arg NAME "John" '.[] | select(.group | contains ($NAME))
```

this should return only the name John, but it is displaying all values where John is included..
Eg: displays Johnny, Johnie

It's giving these values also as output.
I tried with including * and also tried with single and double quotes. If I use * its giving empty output. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: `jq` has nothing to do with `jQuery`

Comment: Please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.

Comment: Is `.group` a string or an array? If it's an array, use `$NAME | IN(.group)` where `IN` is indeed capitalized

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#contains(element)) on `contains`

> The filter `contains(b)` will produce `true` if b is completely contained within the input. A string B is contained in a string A if B is a substring of A.

Therefore, `contains` also matches on substrings. Use `==` for exact matches, i.e. comparing with the entire string only:

```
jq --arg NAME "John" '.[] | select(.group == $NAME)'
```

Comment: I tried this also. Its giving empty output.

Comment: @Vanaan If you provided your input JSON, we could see why. Most probably, the input array or object contains no items having a field with name "group" and value "John".

Comment: `jq --arg NAME "John" '.[] | select(.group == $NAME) | select(.jobgroup == $AGE) | select.(workgroup == $WORK)  | .sequence.commands[0].exec' /home/ubuntu/workgroups.json | cut -d' ' -f5 | sed 's/\"//' `

my jq expression will be in this format and it suppose to pass all these arguments and should provide correct output. It means it should give output only if all conditions are matching exactly

Comment: @Vanaan In your extended command, you only declare `$NAME`, the other variables are still undeclared (which should lead to further errors). Also, you can combine all of those `select` conditions using `and`. But above all, you just provided an extended version of your command, not the input JSON asked for, so there's still no way for us to see as for why it behaves like that.